# Hiding a sub menu as page loads by sliding up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/tw6sdod9/4/

When you click run or refresh, when the page loads, the sub menu under 'Texts' slides up. How can I change this so we don't see it happening when the page loads but keep the menu sliding at 400 the rest of the time when using the menu?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('li ul').slideDown(0);


$('.no-js li a').on("click", function () {
    $('ul#inner-li ul').slideUp(400);
    if($(this).siblings('ul').is(":visible"))
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp(400);
    else
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown(400);
});
  jQuery('#texts').click();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li ul').slideDown(0);
    $("#inner-li-texts").hide(0); /* patch here */

    $('.no-js li a').on("click", function () {
        $('ul#inner-li ul').slideUp(400);
        if($(this).siblings('ul').is(":visible"))
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp(400);
        else
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown(400);
    });
      //jQuery('#texts').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="no-js">
  <li class="caps"><a href="#">Works</a>
      <ul id="inner-li">
                <li><a href="blog.html">blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="portraits.html">Portraits</a></li>
                <li><a href="paintings.html">Paintings</a></li>
                <li><a href="drawings.html">Drawings</a></li>
                <li><a href="photography.html">Photography</a></li>
                
      </ul></li>
      <li class="caps"><a id="texts" href="#">Texts</a>
      <ul id="inner-li-texts">
                <li><a class="current" href="#essay-one">Essay one</a></li>
                <li><a href="#essay-two">Essay two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#essay-three">Essay three</a></li>
               </ul>
                </li>
  <li class="caps"><a href="../news.htm">News</a></li>
  <li class="caps"><a href="../biography.htm">Biography</a></li>
  
  </ul>
```

You have used `.click` to trigger the animation, I just tell it to be hidden (`.hide(0)`) at start of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of triggering the click after the code has been set, you can call that specific ul to slide back up, before the click is even set:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li ul').slideDown(0);
    $('#inner-li-texts').slideUp(0);


    $('.no-js li a').on("click", function () {
        $('ul#inner-li ul').slideUp(400);
        if($(this).siblings('ul').is(":visible"))
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp(400);
        else
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown(400);
    });
});
```